# DDR2 RAM Frequency

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Lenovo R61.

Am planning to upgrade the RAM.

Which version of DDR2 (667 or 800) should I use?

CPU-Z screenshot: http://valid.canardpc.com/show_oc.php?id=1545560

Comment: The one the product manuals recommend.

Comment: My laptop didnt come with a product manual, it was a bulk purchase by the university without any papers given to us

Comment: It's called Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RAM Speed : 332.7 MHz (3:5) @ 5-5-5-1

Get 667 MHz.

Comment: how do you translate "332.7 MHz (3:5) @ 5-5-5-1" to 667 Mhz?

Comment: @Akash: It's *not* 667MHz. It's 667 million transfers a second. "Double data rate" means the frequency is half the transfer rate.

Answer (score 1):

The R61 doesn't require DDR2 PC6400 (800mhz)--it's run with PC5300 (667mhz).  I'd go with whichever one you can get cheaper.